# How to formulate Dynamic Excel Ranges

Tags: excel

```
Column C   Column D   Column E
  14          6            1
  11                   16.52
   5                   82.64
  30                       0
  60                       0
  12                       0
   9                       0
   4                       0
```

I have these three columns and they are all user input so they are numerically dynamic.
 Column C has a range of numbers, some less than the value in Column D.
 Column E has values greater than 0.
 The 0 in Column E signifies do not calculate the same row in Column C.
 What I need to do is take the corresponding Non-Zero values in Column E and test the values in Column C to be less than Column D.
 Then take the difference between Column D and any values in Column C less than Column D and divide that value by the COUNT of Column C equal or greater than Column D.
 For example as it is now. In Column C I would not evaluate Row 5:9 because Column E has 0 in those rows.
 Column C Row 4 is the value 5, which is 1 less than Column D 6 so the difference is 1. There are 2 values in Column C that are equal or greater than Column D
 so the result is 1/2 = .5

Another Example:

```
Column C   Column D   Column E
  14          6            1
  11                   16.52
   5                   82.64
  30                       0
  60                       0
  12                       0
   9                       0
   4                   19.56
```

In this example there are 4 used values in Column C Row 2,3,4,9. Two of the values are less than Column D by D2-C4 + D2-C9 = 3.
 The result is 3/2 = 1.5

Another Example:

```
Column C   Column D   Column E
  14          6            1
  11                   16.52
   5                       0
  30                       0
  60                       0
   6                   18.66
   9                       0
   4                       0
```

The result is 0/3 = 0

I've tried to figure something out with INDEX/MATCH, SUMPRODUCT, COUNTIFS, SMALL, INDIRECT, MIN, but this is beyond my EXCEL capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SUMIFS, a couple of COUNTIFS and some math should do it.

```
=(D2*COUNTIFS(E:E, "<>"&0, C:C, "<"&D2)-SUMIFS(C:C, E:E, "<>"&0, C:C, "<"&D2))/COUNTIFS(E:E, "<>"&0, C:C, ">="&D2)
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your time. The result of your formula based on my first example is giving me a 1 and it should be .5.

Comment: Hi, I tightened up the ranges and it worked great!! I had a spurious "5" in E26 that it picked up...

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I'm glad things worked out for you.